# Navigation bar font

Tags: html, fonts, mailchimp, navigationbar

I am in need of some help with the custom nav bar I have created for an email template on Mailchimp. I'm not a coder but I've managed to create a nav bar which links to my web pages. However, the font that is currently showing in the nav bar is Times New Roman I believe, and I desperately want to change it to Source Sans Pro.

The current code looks as follows:

```
<style>

ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}

li {
float: left;
}

li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
background-color: #111;
}
</style>
```

What do I add to make the current font change to Source Sans Pro?

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to link it in your HTML as such

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

and then use it in your CSS with whatever selector (ID/Class/Element)

`font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;`

to make your entire document this font:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<style>

* {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}

li {
float: left;
}

li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
background-color: #111;
}
</style>
```

Comment: glad to help my friend.

check out `fonts.google.com` they give you the <link> tag and all of the css. its a cut and paste job. its a great resource